# Do any ordered pairs of algebraic numbers satisfy this function?

Tags: reference-request, logarithms, exponential-function, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

> Q: Does there exist an algebraic number $x,$ s.t. $f(x)$ is also an algebraic number?

$f(x)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\bigg)$ for $x\ne0,1.$

I would like to prove that the set of points $(x,f(x))$ is the empty set, for algebraic $x.$

Are there any promising approaches to solve this?

Comment: If $x\ne1$ then there is a positive answer $x=0 \implies f(0)=1 $

Comment: When did the logarithm become defined on $\{0\}$?  In fact, this $f$ is maximally defined on $(0,\infty)$ if we are thinking of it as a real function.  If we are thinking of it as a complex function (valid since the setting is algebraics), then there is freedom to choose a branch cut, but not the branch point: $0$.

Comment: wolfram alpha says that $f(0)=1$

Comment: Then apparently, Wolfram Alpha has misled you by silently taking $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$ instead of correctly observing $\ln 0$ is undefined, so $f$ is undefined at $x = 0$.

Comment: Always be wary of trusting a computer. Programmers make errors too.